# Setting chart gap width in EPPlus / Office Open Xml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, epplus

How can I set the Gap Width value on a column/bar chart in EPPlus?

I have not found a built-in property for this and am expecting I will need to manipulate the chart's Xml, but I've been unable to find the Office Open Xml syntax for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported in EPPLus.
For example:

```
var barChart = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes[0] as ExcelBarChart;
barChart.GapWidth = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by creating what I wanted in a standard Excel sheet, and then looking at the underlying XML it had crated.

I set the Gap Width on an existing chart using the Excel, saved the workbook, renamed the file extension to .zip, and found the corresponding chart XML file within the Zip.

In this case I found the element `<c:gapWidth val="15" />` at the following location in the chart's XML: `c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:barChart`

I highly recommend this method for solving similar OOXML syntax queries, as the documentation I've seen so far is very dense and not easy to navigate, whereas learning by example in this way helped me find the answer in seconds.